# How to extract the Location: HTTP header field with libcurl?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I m using libcurl as a http client in my application. I can send and receive http messages with libcurl.

I want to extract the `location` field from the received http message when I got a message with http 302 as indicated above.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://192.168.201.1
Content-Length: 0
```

How I can extract the `location` field when I got http 302 message?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html

Comment: @el.pescado Should I make redirect with libcurl to get the http url redirect info? because I do not want to. I just want to extract the info that's all.

Comment: Did you read the linked page?  "receive the URL a redirect *would* take you to if you would enable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION".  In other words it tells you where the redirect would go to if you were to follow it.  In particular, if the redirect is a relative URL, it will take the original URL and figure out the absolute target URL.

Comment: @el.pescado it works. Thanks. Could you post your comment as answer and I will accept your answer (inchallah)

Comment: Based on this question, I've also added a getredirect example to the curl site showing how to use it: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getredirect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need processed, absolute URL that you woult land on when following the redirect, use [CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html) option. See also the [getredirect](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getredirect.html) example.

When you need raw value of `Location` header, you need to implement [CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) callback and wait for the header to arrive.